# Force windows to wake up from standby mode

Tags: c#, windows, events

I have a system with an external device that should be able under circumstances to 'wake up' windows if it's in standby mode. I found a lot of answer/response to put the operating system in standby but nothing to force it to wake up.

Is there any way to do this in C# ?

Comment: Don't know if this maybe applies to you, but there's "Wake on LAN" ...

Comment: ^^ That is: you can configure Windows, so that when it receives a special "magic packet" on LAN, it wakes up the system. That would of course mean, that your devices have LAN connection. And you need to provide a means to configure Windows for that feature and your device to target the machine it is connected to.

Comment: Short answer: Where would your program run if the CPU is powered off? Longer Story: https://superuser.com/questions/1017571/is-the-cpu-active-in-sleep-mode